# Can't get a newline when reading from CSV file and printing to Text file

Tags: python, csv, text, newline

I'm new to coding and have tried working this out myself, to no avail!
I'm imputing rows from a csv file and writing them to a text file. The rows have a lot of data but I only want certain fields. Ive just about got it to write the fields I want i.e **Reference number 12345, Date: 20/5/17, Incident Type: text...** etc

The problem is all the rows are bunched together with no lines between them. Ideally I would like two or three lines apart i.e

1. Reference number 12345, Date: 20/5/17, Incident Type: text...
2. Reference number 23117, Date: 22/5/17, Incident Type: text...
3. Reference number 23117, Date: 22/5/17, Incident Type: text...

Eventually I would like to be able to write only rows that contain particular keywords i.e by Incident Type or particular date. At the moment tho I would be happy if I could get newlines between the rows so that it was easy to read.
I have tried just about everything. "\n" just seems to print in the text file rather than create a new line.

This is the code im using, its probably a bit crude but I have gotten this far by trial and error.

```
import csv
import os

with open("raw.csv", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        r = [row for row in r]
        r = [row[4] + "---" + row[1] + "---" + row[6] for row in r]

with open("txtfile.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(r)+"\r\n")
    print("Written successfully")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to print a new line after each line, not after the whole string. Start with:

```
with open("raw.csv", "r") as f, open("txtfile.txt", "w") as output:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        output.write("{} --- {} --- {}\n".format(row[4], row[1], row[6]))
```

and take it from there. For additional formatting of your text file check the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Also, you might want to use a 'proper' line separator for your platform (which roughly means `\n` for everything normal as above, and `\r\n` for Windows) if you intend to read your text files in applications not designed in this century. You can get the current platform's preferred separator from the `os` module: [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep).